# MacBook Air 2010 OS X 10.6.8 w/Broadcom wifi disconnecting: "Disassociated because station leaving"

Tags: snow-leopard, wifi

The wifi on my MacBook Air 2010 keeps dropping the connection at home with a Linksys WRT160N router running `DD-WRT v24-sp1 (07/27/08) std`. Other devices maintain their connection to the router just fine.

I'm getting these messages in my kernel.log:

```
air-ethernet kernel[0]: AirPort: Link Down on en0. Reason 8 (Disassociated because station leaving).
```

Does anyone know the canonical solution to this problem? There are threads on Apple Support Communities that go on for 70 pages, but no high-profile links that have a definitive answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and I've also been looking around a lot. The only thing I find is that if you have an Atheros Wi-Fi hardware in your Mac (I just found out that I did, mid-2011-iMac) this will help:

http://rys.pixeltards.com/2011/09/04/osx-lion-wifi.html